# Keycloak .well-known/openid-configuration is not responding with "https" protocol for the endpoints

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

We have deployed Keycloak behind a load balancer which is F5. The OIDC clients are sitting in public network uses "https" for all communications. The SSL is terminated in F5 and the packets are forwarded to Keycloak (say on port 8080).
The OIDC client is designed in a such a way so as to use the endpoints (like `/token` etc) that it receives in the response for  the `.well-known/openid-configuration` request.

The problem here is that the `.well-known` config is responding with URLs with protocol as `http` for all the endpoints where as client is expecting protocol with  `https`. Because of this client is not able to make secure connection to these URLs.

Question is - how can we have responses for `.well-known/openid-configuration` request return with endpoints with protocol `https` ; like the one mentioned below

```
{
  "issuer":"https://<domain>/auth/realms/master",
  "authorization_endpoint":"https://<domain>/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
  "token_endpoint":"https://<domain>/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
  .......
}
```

We have followed the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.5/server_installation/topics/clustering/load-balancer.html).

I.e in F5 added the `x-Forwarded-For` and `x-Forwarded-Proto` and made the respective keycloak configuration changes as indicated in the documentation. 
Is there any configuration or setting I might be missing?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm running into the same problem using Keycloak behind a Kubernetes Ingress

Comment: I also run into the same issue, please share how you fix it

Answer (score 4):

I've been struggling with the same problem for days now and finally figured it out. The problem is that Keycloak uses the `X-Forwarded-Proto` HTTP header when running behind a proxy to determine if the incoming request was made via HTTPS. Your load balancer (in my case AWS ELB) needs to set this header correctly (see [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32194167/x-forwarded-proto-for-rails-behind-nginx-behind-elb)).

When using ELB, you need to make sure that either:

1. Your listener is set to `HTTPS`
2. Your listener is set to `TCP` and the receiving backend supports the [Proxy Protocol](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancing-adds-support-for-proxy-protocol/)

In my case, my listeners were set to `TCP` but the backend was not configured accordingly. I found that [NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/) and Kubernetes' [NGINX Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-proxy-protocol) support this option.

Answer (score 3):

From what I gather, it can be done (I have not used it personally) on the realm level. Though it is long process explaining which fully is beyond the scope of this answer. Instead, I am giving the link to a document.

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/18.0/server_installation/#_clustering

Comment: Link is broken.